# With PhatomJS can you inject CSS to page.content?

Tags: phantomjs, code-injection

With PhantomJS, I'm having trouble rendering screenshots of external pages using flex.  As a workaround, I'd like to add some CSS to the page.content of the opened page.

Is this possible?

I'm missing some foundational knowledge because I'm getting errors with everything I tried.

$file = 'screenshot.png';

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;

  *** content.add-css-to-header***

  page.render('".$file."'); //Rendered with my CSS flexbox fix.
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I'd expect it to update the html code, render the page (w/flexbox fixed) and take a screenshot to look as it does with a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PhantomJS's rendering engine is very obsolete and the project itself is discontinued. Currently the best alternative to migrate to from PhantomJS is [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) which uses the latest Chromium for rendering pages. It is maitained by Google itself and is now being actively developed.